# Removing inherited property of an element (box-sizing)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I am using a jQuery light box plugin on a bootstrap site. It has `box-sizing: border-box` set via universal selector.

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The light box div does not appear right because of this (sometimes a vertical scrollbar appears). Once we remove this through web inspector it appears ok. Is there any way to remove the box-sizing property of this particular element. 
 `box-sizing:''` or `box-sizing:none` does not appear to work.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/#universal-box-sizing-with-inheritance) if you wish to have both `border-box` reset and `box-sizing` customization.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `box-sizing`<sup>[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183522(v=vs.85).aspx), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)</sup> CSS property default is `box-sizing: content-box;`.
Have you tried to use it to override the inherited style?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I had to apply it to few more child elements and it worked.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me on the new Bootstrap 3 allowing me to integrate Bootstrap with an existing (non-Bootstrap) site.

Comment: @GokulKav i am facing same issue what else changes did u make ? they may be helpful for me

Comment: Even though Chrome devtools says it is applying the style, and even though I applied it to all children using `.elem *, .elem *::after, .elem *::before`, and even trying `!important`, it still wouldn't make a difference until I literally duplicated the selector that originally applied it, as `* {box-sizing: content-box;}` and hit all possible elements with that, apparently.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem with bootstrap and I did override the box-sizing CSS property for `<a>` like this,

```
a *,
a *:before,
a *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

Customize it for your need.

Answer (score 8):

you can use

```css
*:not(.classname){
  box-sizing : border-box;
}
```

`classname` will be the class of element you want to exclude from the universal selector.

Answer (score -5):

Override like this:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box!important;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to remove border-box. not add importance to border-box.